# Group By,Order by DateTime

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have nearly 15000 data rows with the first column containing date in the format: 
`2012-05-10 09:00:00.000`

I need this data to be sorted by year then month, then day, then hour so for example:

```
         2012-05-10 09:00:00.000
         2012-05-10 10:00:00.000
         2012-05-10 11:00:00.000
         2012-05-10 12:00:00.000
         2012-05-11 09:00:00.000
         2012-05-11 10:00:00.000
         2012-05-11 11:00:00.000
         2012-05-11 12:00:00.000
         2012-06-01 02:00:00.000
         2012-06-01 03:00:00.000
         2012-06-01 04:00:00.000
         2012-06-01 05:00:00.000
```

Current `SQL` Query to do this is below:

`SELECT MIN(Datetime)
GROUP BY DATEPART(M,jmusa_LOG1.DateTime),DATEPART(D,jmusa_LOG1.DateTime),DATEPART(HH,jmusa_LOG1.DateTime)
HAVING MIN(jmusa_LOG1.DateTime) NOT IN(SELECT DateTime FROM AverageRawData)`

`ORDER BY  DATEPART(M,jmusa_LOG1.DateTime),DATEPART(D,jmusa_LOG1.DateTime),DATEPART(HH,jmusa_LOG1.DateTime)`

Comment: You can't sort the result by year, as that is not included in what you group by. The values `2012-05-10 09:00` and `2011-05-10 09:00` for example will end up in the same group.

Comment: Your current query does not compile.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `FROM` clause.

Comment: If you just want it sorted, why do you have a group by and a having clause?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a normal date sort, so you can just do:

```
select MyDate
from AverageRawData
order by MyDate
```

If you don't want duplicates, add `DISTINCT` like this:

```
select distinct MyDate
from AverageRawData
order by MyDate
```

If this does not meet your requirements, please provide sample data used to generate your output example.

Comment: I am using the Group by and order by because I have aggregates in the other columns that are not shown in the code above

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output.

Comment: Since the data is so large I put it in a csv file: http://www.sendspace.com/file/c1rxlr  I want the averaged data to be ordered by the month and the date and the year.  So when the Select statement averages out the other columns they will all be arranged according to the date and according to the hour